# why my site page topic behindnavbar (bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I try to see when I click navbar then I want to see the topic, but it is showing the topic under navbar. I try to give margin, but it doesn't work. Is someone help me with how can I solve this problem.

[Web site showing like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4vki.png)

[But I want to see like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcN46.png)

```
there is code: https://codepen.io/rero34/pen/mdqGyVo
```

Comment: In my browser I can see the Hizmetlerimiz header nicely under the carousel.. however the carousel is not visible on your screenshots at all.

Comment: @ino  OP is referring to heading positions when clicking different sections in the navbar.

Comment: @カメロン oh, you are right, I missed that little but very important detail..

Comment: @homie23 before you post a new question saying something like "why are there huge margins at the start of each section?" - please look at my solution first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are using Bootstrap which is great. But my first impression was you have too many manual styles going on, especially for using a CSS framework. Without over-explaining it, the main reason your anchors aren't starting at the top of the section is because your `id`'s are starting at the span, which is not the start of the section. You should put the `id`'s on the sections themselves.

Then, the next issue comes from the use of padding on your sections and excessive margins on headings. Without going through and cleaning all of those up, let's look at ways around it.

> scroll-margin is used to adjust an element’s snap area (the box that defines where the element will be snapped to).

I added some [`scroll-margin-top`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-margin/) on each section. I found that roughly `5.5em` is the sweet spot in your case.

Your code has too many characters for a stack snippet, so take a look in the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kameronmayers/pen/yLPxNgE).

Comment: i check your codepen and i edit my code but not showing like your codeopen. where is error editing?

Comment: @homie23 I made changes to your HTML also as far as classes go. I removed padding on some sections that don't need it which is causing offsets. I also removed it from the navbar. Have you heard of [meld](https://meldmerge.org/)? You can use that software to compare the two codes side by side and see exactly what I changed.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is set the `margin-top: 0;` in the `_robot.css` file. for the 3rd-level header tag.

You can overcome this default settings with your custom style of the `H3` tag to set the appropriate `margin-top: 100px !important;`. Customize it to your needs, I take the 100px as random value.

```css
    h3{
       font-weight: 700;
       margin-bottom: 50px;    
       margin-top: 100px !important;
    }
```

**Edit**
I found you have the `margin-top` for `h3` defined several times. There might be the conflict which cause it. Next occurenc in your style is later in

```css
    .services h3{
      margin-top: 80px;
    }
```

Comment: thank u helping me. you solve my problem :)

Comment: Downvoted because this solution creates huge margins at the top of the headings. Effectively taking a toll on UI. Not to mention, this is not the proper approach to fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a natural z-index side-effect of using a fixed navbar. See if it makes a difference to add `margin-top` to the element immediately following the navbar. That seems to be `div id="myCarousel"`. The margin you add should be the same 'px' tall as your navbar.